# How to Offset Index Match result in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

If Sheet2!A2 value is found within a string on Sheet1!A:A, then Sheet1!"B2" = Offset(Sheet2!"A2",0,1)
I.e., I have a range of values on Sheet2 that are a part of values in a range on Sheet1. If a value on Sheet2 is found in the range of values on Sheet1, then I want my result to be the adjacent value on Sheet1 to be the adjacent value from Sheet2. 
How is this best accomplished in VBA?
[image: Example]

This is the code I need to incorporate the formula into:
***The code is now functional***

```
Sub ListAllFiles()

    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
       Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim myExt1 As String
    Dim myExt2 As String
        myExt1 = "pptx"
        myExt2 = "pdf"

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
'Get the folder object associated with the directory
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("\\sitefs\www\htdocs\c13\comm\IMS\Schedules\")

    Dim objFolderItems As FolderItems
    Dim objFolderItem As FolderItem
        Set objFolderItems = objFolder.Items()

'Loop through the Files collection
Dim fOwner As String
Dim fAuthor As String
Dim dlm As String

ws.UsedRange.Clear
 ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "The current files found in " & objFolder & " are:"
 ws.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Date Last Modified"
 ws.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Owner"
 ws.Cells(1, 5).Value = "Report Date:"
 ws.Cells(1, 6).Value = Now
 Range("A1").EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
  For Each objFile In objFolder.Items
  dlm = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFile, 3)
  If InStr(objFile.Name, "FINAL") Then GoTo 50
   If Year(CDate(dlm)) < Year(Now) Then GoTo 50
   If InStr(objFile.Name, myExt1) Or InStr(objFile.Name, myExt2) Then
    Dim x As Integer
    x = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
        ws.Cells(x, 1).Value = objFile.Name
        'Link cell to file
            Cells(x, 1).Select
                Selection.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:=objFile.Path
        ws.Cells(x + 0, 2).Value = dlm
    End If
50 Next

'Added this and it's now working
 Dim oRng As Range
   Dim cRng As Range
   x = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  Set oRng = Range("C2")
  Set cRng = Range("C2:C" & x)
    oRng.FormulaArray = _
        "=OFFSET(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$19,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$19,a2))),),0)),,2)"
   cRng.FillDown

 Columns("A:B").Sort key1:=Range("B2"), _
      order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
    Columns.AutoFit
     'Clean up!
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set oRng = Nothing
Set cRng = Nothing 
End Sub
```

Comment: (Can you copy/paste your Sheet1 and Sheet2 tables? It will help us put the data into Excel to help you!)

Comment: In which line do you see the formula being used?

Comment: @ScottCraner OP is saying this is the code that imitates the formula as you asked below. Not literally trying to incorporate it into the code.

Comment: @findwindow `This is the code I need to incorporate the formula into:`

Comment: @ScottCraner I know. Let's say it's my intuition that OP means something other than what was articulated. Edit: I could very well be wrong.

Comment: Anyways, `If InStr(objFile.Name, myExt1)` needs `> 0` after it?

Comment: @findwindow as I read through the code, the OP is loading sheet1 column A with links to files.  That is what the code is currently doing.  Now the OP wants to figure out how to match a key word in the names of those files to a table in another spread sheet and return the value in column B of the spread sheet into column B of sheet 1.  That part does not exist in the current code above.  And No the `>0` is not needed, anything more than 0 will resolve to true.

Comment: @ScottCraner Oh duh XD You're probably right. I read it the original question sans code as an "example" of what the OP really wanted. There was never two sheets where OP wanted to index/match, just files that OP wanted to separate between powerpoint and pdf files. Edit: again, all wild guesses on my part ^_^;

Comment: You could always us Worksheet.Evaluate `Cells(x, 3).Value = ws.Evaluate("=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$9,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$9," & Cells(x, 1).Address(0,0) & "))),),0))")`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This formula will find the values in Sheet 2 in the values in Sheet 1 and return the appropriate value:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$9,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$9,A2))),),0))
```

[image]

What is happening:

The inner INDEX is creating an array of TRUE/FALSE that, In this case is 8 objects.

Because as it iterates through the values on Sheet2 it either returns a number or an error.

The ISNUMBER returns a TRUE/FALSE based on that outcome.

Then the MATCH iterates through the array till it finds TRUE and returns that index to the outer Index formula.

Which then returns the value in that array which is at the index from the MATCH.

Comment: Nice! I should have thought about using `Search()`, since there can be "New York", or "New Mexico", etc.

Comment: what forces the iteration of the rows the RANGE A2:A9?  I thought this was a CSE formula when I was reading it but you did not describe it as such.  Is it because its in the range/array portion of the index?

Comment: Yeah...My Excel doesn't seem to want to evaluate Search(Sheet2!A2:A9,A2).  I wonder if this is a version of Excel thing...

Comment: @NicholasPatton It has to be part of an array formula, It will not do it on its own.  What the INDEX, is doing is creating an array of TRUE/FALSE that, In this case is 8 objects.  Because as it iterates through the values on Sheet2 it either returns a number or an error, which then the ISNUMBER return a TRUE/FALSE based on that outcome.  Then the MATCH iterates through the array till it finds TRUE and returns that index to the outer Index formula.  Which then returns the value in that array which is at the index from the MATCH.

Comment: @ForwardEd this is a non CSE array formula akin to SUMPRODUCT

Comment: Very nice formula Scott! Your mastery and rate of learning are astonishing :)  Here is the formula I came up with, which is almost identical to yours: `=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$8,MATCH(1,INDEX(COUNTIF(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$8&"*"),),0))`

Comment: @tigeravatar you are very kind.  Just standing on the shoulders of giants like yourself.  I like to troll on questions I cannot answer, to learn.  I believe I got this method from you.

Comment: So about the VBA part? The intention of the formula is to be incorporated into an existing code as an if(instr()) statement

Comment: If you want vba, do not use the formula in vba, simple mimic what the formula does.  Loop through each cell in column A in sheet one.  Inside that loop, loop thorugh each cell in column A in sheet 2 and using  the Instr() function test whether the value in sheet2 is in sheet1's value, if so make the value in Column B in sheet 1 = to the value in column b  in sheet 2 on their respective rows then exit the inner for loop.  If you want vba, we need to see what you have tried.  SO is not a code for me service. @Adavid02

Comment: @ScottCraner, That's fair enough; post edited to include code.

Comment: @ScottCraner Ah -- I missed the "array formula" detail.  Very neat -- I'll have to play with that a bit.

Comment: Got it working; thanks to all! I edited the post to include the added code.

Answer (score 1):

Your main idea is if you have "Texas" in Sheet 1, col. A, you want "Gardner" to be in the col. B?

You can use this formula, in your Sheet1 B2 cell:

`=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$4,MATCH(TRIM(LEFT(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2))),Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4,0))`

(Expand the ranges as necessary)

Comment: This won't work for the last one on his list.  But if that is a typo and there is always a space after the state and the state is always the first word then this is the best solution.

Comment: This is a good method -- but it might get messed up on values like New York.  For instance, if you add New Mexico to your list of states -- then this equation is going to return the same owner based on whether New York or New Mexico is further up the list on Sheet 2.

Comment: Basically -- you can use this solution if you format the names of your PPTX files judiciously keep Scott and my comments in mind.  Otherwise, you'd have to make a lot of nested "IF" statments, create a table of PPTX files (rows) by State names (columns) and search in each cell, or use VBA and do some looping.

Comment: I think your best option here is to use VBA to create a Macro that internally builds a 2D array. You could loop through this and check if there is a match, then dynamically create a formula to be placed in each cell. Then fill down the formula for every row.

Comment: @NicholasPatton - Ah, good point on "New York".  There's a better way I'm sure (*cough* ScottCraner *cough*).

Comment: @timthebomb that depends, If the dataset is not large then an array formula like the one I proposed in my answer will work.  I agree if the dataset is in excess of 20,000 or 30,000 then vba is the way to go.

Comment: @ScottCraner good call. your solution is best in small datasets.